# PHP Key Multiple Values to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, key

I have an array that has a key, and the value is an array with values;
 The key is a word, and the values are synonyms; so it would look like this

```
$arr = array();
$syns = ['hi','wassip','yeaboy','heya','heo'];
$arr["hello"] = $syns;

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
   foreach($value as $word){
      echo $key."   ".$word."\n";
   }
}
```

this will disply each word, and each synonym for the word.

Can this be converted into json format? I am trying to pass this from one page to another, either through javascript, php, or however. How can I pass this array of synonyms for each word?

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your `$arr` variable?

Answer (score 0):

simply use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

**Example**

```
$syns = ['hi','wassip','yeaboy','heya','heo'];
$arr["hello"] = $syns;

$jsonFormat = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thats what I thought, but how do I pull out the info.  am i going to use json.parse(jsonObject) ? and am i passing this object between pages though php or js?

Comment: if you want to decode this json in php you can use `josn_docode`, in jquery you can use `$.parseJson(jsonObj)`